# How to update a "label" in ViewController.cs from another C# file in Xamarin MacOS development?

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin

I am working on a small MacOS app in Xamarin and using 'Visual Studio for MAC'. I am unable to figure out how to update the value of a label in the ViewController.cs file from another .cs file.

```
using System;
using AppKit;
using Foundation;

namespace FramesMac
{

    public partial class ViewController : NSViewController
    {
        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            lbl_message.StringValue="Processing..."
        }

        public override NSObject RepresentedObject
        {
            get
            {
                return base.RepresentedObject;
            }
            set
            {
                base.RepresentedObject = value;
                // Update the view, if already loaded.
            }
        }

    }
    }
```

I simply want to update lbl_message.StringValue="Processing..." from another .cs file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in my knowledge would be using Actions, first create a method:

```
private void SetLabelText(string Text)
{
   lbl_message.StringValue=Text;
}
```

Now pass the reference of this method to the next class using actions through the constructor:

```
public AnotherClass(Action<string> MyLabelCallback)
```

make an instance of it from the viewController like:

```
new AnotherClass(SetLabelText);
```

After getting it you can just call this method and pass a string to set the new text:

```
MyLabelCallback("Boom");
```

Comment: Added the following code in ViewController.cs to update the label text

 InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    myLabel.StringValue = "someString";
                });